# Zephyr to Test Rail migration - Is it possible?

Tags: test-management, excel, jira

We are currently looking at Testrail as an alternative to using the Zephyr plugin within JIRA as Testrail looks to give us better test case and reporting management than Zephyr does.

Currently faced with the usual problem when changing tools of how to migrate our existing test cases from one to the other.

I know there are importer tools to get Excel spreadsheet cases into Testrail, so that is ok. The problem I'm facing is how to get the test scripts out of Zephyr.

Does anyone know of any similar plugins to export test cases/scripts from Zephyr to Excel?

I've tried using the inbuilt export function, but it only seems to export the basic case details, not the individual test steps.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having done some further investigation myself, it appears there are multiple ways to extract parts of the tests from Zephyr.

1. If you use the 'Search' function to locate a test and then choose to Export via the Export button in the test case frame itself then you get a summary of the test information but WITHOUT the test steps. If you use the 'Search' function to locate a test and then choose to Export via the Export button in the test case frame itself then you get a summary of the test information but WITHOUT the test steps.
2. If you use the Export button from the top of the window (there should be 'Share', 'Export' and 'Tools' buttons) you get additional options. Selecting the option for 'Excel (All fields)' will extract full test case information, including all the fields.
3. A slightly quicker way to extract them is to Search for executed tests and from the 'Executed Tests Summary', select a test via the checkbox next to the test and select 'Export'. This gives the option to extract the test information, including test steps, as CSV, XLS, HTML, XML or RSS.

This is a large file and the test step information not readily apparent. (My steps were started in column CH!)

It is also worth noting that each line within the test step appears in a different cell, so importing to another tool will definitely require a lot of reformatting of the test step information.

Answer (score 1):

If You company bought ZAPI (Zephyr API) along with Zephyr, You always can write migration scripts for e.g. in python. In my recent jobs I test both Zephyr and Test Rail, and I must said that, Test Rail is fantastic and has REST API more friendly than Zephyr. 
Unfortunately we must choose Zephyr due to lower price (company has its own servers, don't want accept cloud solutions that was way cheaper).

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll investigate and find out if we have the full API version. Ideally we would prefer not to have to write scripts though.